# From (a->b) to (MyType->MyType)

Tags: haskell

I have defined a simple algebraic (concrete) data type, MyType :

```
data MyTpe = MyBool Bool | MyInt Int
```

... and I am trying to find a way to "convert" arbitrary functions (a->b), where a and b are either Bool or Int, into the associated (MyType->MyType) functions.

This does the job, it converts (a->b) into *Maybe* (MyType->MyType) (see [1] below) :

```
import Data.Typeable

data MyTpe = MyBool Bool | MyInt Int deriving Show

liftMyType :: (Typeable a, Typeable b) => (a -> b) -> Maybe (MyTpe -> MyTpe)
liftMyType f =  case castIntInt f of
                  Just g    -> Just $ liftIntInt g
                  Nothing   -> 
                    case castIntBool f of
                     Just g    -> Just $ liftIntBool g
                     Nothing   -> 
                       case castBoolInt f of
                       Just g    -> Just $ liftBoolInt g
                       Nothing   -> 
                         case castBoolBool f of
                         Just g    -> Just $ liftBoolBool g
                         Nothing   -> Nothing

castIntInt :: (Typeable a, Typeable b) => (a -> b) -> Maybe (Int -> Int)
castIntInt f =  cast f :: Maybe (Int -> Int)

castIntBool :: (Typeable a, Typeable b) => (a -> b) -> Maybe (Int -> Bool)
castIntBool f =  cast f :: Maybe (Int -> Bool)

castBoolInt :: (Typeable a, Typeable b) => (a -> b) -> Maybe (Bool -> Int)
castBoolInt f =  cast f :: Maybe (Bool -> Int)

castBoolBool :: (Typeable a, Typeable b) => (a -> b) -> Maybe (Bool -> Bool)
castBoolBool f =  cast f :: Maybe (Bool -> Bool)

liftIntInt :: (Int -> Int) -> (MyTpe -> MyTpe)
liftIntInt f (MyInt x) = MyInt (f x)

liftIntBool :: (Int -> Bool) -> (MyTpe -> MyTpe)
liftIntBool f (MyInt x) = MyBool (f x)

liftBoolInt :: (Bool -> Int) -> (MyTpe -> MyTpe)
liftBoolInt f (MyBool x) = MyInt (f x)

liftBoolBool :: (Bool -> Bool) -> (MyTpe -> MyTpe)
liftBoolBool f (MyBool x) = MyBool (f x)
```

However that's quite ugly and does not scale well : what if I want to extend MyType that way?

```
data MyTpe = MyBool Bool | MyInt Int | MyString String
```

... Or what if I also want to convert (a1 -> a2 -> b), where a1,a2 and b are Bool or Int, into the associated (MyType->MyType->MyType) function?...

**My question** : is there a simple, more elegant and more Haskell-like way to handle this issue?

[1]: liftIntInt function and the like are not defined over *all* MyType elements (eg liftIntInt is not defined for (MyBool x) element). The code is just a reduced case example and in real life I handle this properly.

Comment: I think a simple, elegant and more Haskell-like way to handle the issue is to keep Ints, Bools and Strings separate and thus allow the type system to do its thing straightforwardly, but I don't know your situation.

Answer (score 6):

You're looking for a type

```
goal :: (a -> b) -> (MyType -> MyType)
```

for some "suitable" choices of `a` and `b`. These "suitable" choices are known statically as the definition of `MyType` is known statically.

What you're looking for is a typeclass. In particular, we'll want the `MultiParamTypeClasses` pragma

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}

class MapMyType a b where
  liftMyType :: (a -> b) -> (MyType -> MyType)
```

so now the full type for `liftMyType` is

```
liftMyType :: MapMyType a b => (a -> b) -> (MyType -> MyType)
```

and we can use the typeclass machinery to store the various instantiations of `liftMyType` having it be usable only and exactly when `a` and `b` can be resolved to be types where `liftMyType` is inhabited.

```
instance MapMyType Int  Int  where liftMyType f (MyInt x)  = MyInt  (f x)
instance MapMyType Int  Bool where liftMyType f (MyInt x)  = MyBool (f x)
instance MapMyType Bool Int  where liftMyType f (MyBool x) = MyInt  (f x)
instance MapMyType Bool Bool where liftMyType f (MyBool x) = MyBool (f x)

-- (as a side note, this is a dangerous function to instantiate since it
--  has incomplete pattern matching on its `MyType` typed argument)
```

Now, it's worth mentioning that `MultiParamTypeClasses` often damages inference when used like this. In particular, if we're looking at a fragment of code `liftMyType a b` we have to be able to infer the type of `a` and `b` on their own (e.g., without help from hints being passed "down" from the call to `liftMyType`) otherwise we'll get an ambiguous instance compilation failure. Actually, what makes this especially bad, is that we'll get that compilation failure if *either* `a` or `b` cannot be directly inferred.

In many circumstances, you would want to control this issue using `FunctionalDependencies` allowing a little more inference to "flow" between the two parameters and making ambiguity errors less common.

But in this case, I'd consider it to be a code smell. While the code above works (with caveat to the commented note) it has the feeling of a fragile solution.

Comment: Of course a fully polymorphic function `f :: (a -> b) -> (MyType -> MyType)` cannot exist. I'm really curious why the poster thinks they need such a function...

Comment: @ReinHenrichs may be needed in an implementation of some interpreter

Comment: Actually, such a function does exist. But it isn't very interesting.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question: "is there a simple, more elegant and more Haskell-like way to handle this issue?" There is no elegant or Haskell-like way to solve this problem. Haskell is not a dynamically typed language, and while the designers have managed to fake dynamic typing, you really should avoid it. This question makes it seem like you are trying to fix bad design somewhere with dynamic typing.

You can, however, write a simplified version of your code which is also extensible, using [generics](https://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/GHC.Generics):

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}

import GHC.Generics
import Data.Typeable 

liftFun :: forall a b c . (Generic c, GLiftFun (Rep c), Typeable a, Typeable b) 
        => (a -> b) -> c -> Maybe c
liftFun f x = do 
  a <- gGet (from x)
  b <- gPut (f a)
  return (to b) 

class GLiftFun f where 
  gPut :: Typeable a => a -> Maybe (f q)
  gGet :: Typeable a => f q -> Maybe a 

instance Typeable a => GLiftFun (K1 i a) where 
  gPut = fmap K1 . cast 
  gGet = cast . unK1

instance GLiftFun f => GLiftFun (M1 i c f) where 
  gPut = fmap M1 . gPut
  gGet = gGet . unM1 

instance (GLiftFun f, GLiftFun g) => GLiftFun (f :+: g) where 
  gPut a | Just r <- gPut a = Just (L1 r)
         | Just r <- gPut a = Just (R1 r)
         | otherwise        = Nothing 

  gGet (L1 a) = gGet a 
  gGet (R1 a) = gGet a
```

`liftFun` will work for any type which is a simple sum type, like `Either` or any type you define which is isomorphic to a series of nested `Eithers`. It probably has a sensible extension to product types as well. For example any of the following will work:

```
data MyType = MyBool Bool | MyInt Int deriving (Show, Generic)

data MyType2 = B2 Bool | I2 Int | S2 String deriving (Show, Generic)

type MyType3 = Either String Int
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you could do it in a scalable way:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}
import Data.Typeable

data MyTpe = MyBool Bool | MyInt Int deriving (Show,Typeable)

d :: (Typeable a, Typeable b) => (a->b) -> Maybe (a -> MyTpe)
d f = case (cast f :: (Typeable a) => Maybe (a->Int)) of
        Just f -> Just $ MyInt . f
        _      -> case (cast f :: (Typeable a) => Maybe (a->Bool)) of
                    Just f -> Just $ MyBool . f
                    _      -> Nothing -- add more constructor matching here

e :: (Typeable a, Typeable b) => a -> Maybe (b->MyTpe) -> Maybe MyTpe
e x = (>>= \f -> fmap ($ x) (cast f :: (Typeable a => Maybe (a->MyTpe))))

liftMyType :: (Typeable a, Typeable b) => (a->b) -> MyTpe -> Maybe MyTpe
liftMyType f (MyInt x) = e x $ d f
liftMyType f (MyBool x) = e x $ d f
-- add more constructor matching here
...
> liftMyType ((+1) :: Int->Int) (MyInt 100)
> Just (MyInt 101)
```

You could even get the type you wanted - i.e. `Maybe (MyTpe->MyTpe)` - you don't need to pattern-match on the argument, just then you won't get a total function `MyTpe -> MyTpe` even if it is `Just`.

```
liftMyType = fmap h . d where
  h g = case (cast g :: Maybe (Int->MyTpe)) of
          Just g -> (\(MyInt x)) -> g x
          _      -> case (cast g :: Maybe (Bool->MyTpe)) of
            Just g -> (\(MyBool x)) -> g x
            _      -> Nothing -- add more type matching here
...
> fmap ($ MyInt 100) $ liftMyType ((+1) :: Int->Int)
> Just (MyInt 101)
```